# Can't divide Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can somebody please tell me why this won't work, if I change it to multiplication it will work but not division.

```
SELECT (a.sales_value / a.margin) as GP
```

Comment: Can you define / specify what is not working about it?

Comment: Sorry, getting a division by zero error.

Comment: Is it showing arithmetic overflow error or a.margin=zero? What is meant by not working?

Comment: Ok, so you must be dividing by zero then, if you want something specific to happen when its zero, use a case statement to filter those out to a different scenario. Please figure out what you want to happen, provide example input  / output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid *division by zero*  you can replace zero with NULL:

```
SELECT (a.sales_value / NULLIF(a.margin)) as GP
```

Or apply your own rule:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN a.margin <> 0 
          THEN (a.sales_value / a.margin)
          ELSE a.sales_value -- or 0 or 99 or whatever
       END as GP
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `NULL` where margin is 0
then try this:

```
SELECT CASE a.margin WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE (a.sales_value / a.margin END) as GP
```